Relation between Krull dimension of ideal and its radical
Background: I want to compute the dimension of an affine variety (naive def. as common zeros) defined by an ideal $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ in the affine space $A^n(\mathbb{C})$. I followed Introduction to Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry by E. Kunz and understood that this topological dimension is equal to the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{V}(I))$. Due to Hilbert's Nullstellensatz we have $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{V}(I))=\sqrt{I}$.
However, in practice computing radicals is costly, so I am wondering whether this is also equal to the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$.
I am still pretty new to algebra / algebraic geometry and want to use this for a software package. I would be happy about any references I can cite. I'm assuming this is pretty basic, but I couldn't find it stated anywhere. I hope the reason for this is not that it is false, because here is my attempt in proving it. I'm curious whether it is correct.
Definitions: Let $R\neq\{0\}$ be a polynomial ring. We define $\text{Spec}(R)=\{P\subset R \vert P \text{ prime ideal}\}$, the height of a prime ideal
$$
h:\text{Spec}(R)\to\mathbb{N}, \quad h(P)=\sup\{n\in\mathbb{N}\vert P_0\subset P_1 \subset \dots \subset P_n=P : P_i\in\text{Spec}(R)\}
$$
and the Krull dimension of $R$, $\dim R = \sup_{P\in\text{Spec}(R)} h(P)$.
And similarly, for an ideal $I\subseteq R$, $\dim I := \dim R/I$. For an ideal $J\in R$, $J\supseteq I$, we define $J/I=\{[f]\in R/I \vert f\in J\}$.
Claim: $\dim I = \dim \sqrt{I}$
Proof attempt: We use a version of one of the correspondence (ring isomorphism) theorems from Cox, Little and O’Shea - Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms...:
For an ideal $I\subseteq R$, there is a one-to-one correspondence between the ideals in $R$ that contain $I$ and the ideals in $R/I$.

An ideal $P\subset R$ with $P\supseteq I$ is prime if and only if $P/I$ is prime in $R/I$: Per definition: $$ [f][g]=[fg]\in P/I \iff fg \in P \iff f\in P \lor g\in P \iff [f] \in P/I \lor [g]\in P/I $$
Let $A,B\subseteq R$ be ideals containing $I$. Then $A \subseteq B$ if and only if $A/I\subseteq B/I$ in $R/I$. $$"\Rightarrow": [f]\in A/I \Rightarrow f\in A \Rightarrow f\in B \Rightarrow [f]\in B/I \\ "\Leftarrow": f\in A \Rightarrow [f]\in A/I \Rightarrow [f]\in B/I \Rightarrow f\in B$$
$\{P\subset R \vert P \text{ prime ideal containing} I \} = \{P\subset R \vert P \text{ prime ideal containing} \sqrt{I} \}$. $"\supseteq"$ follows from the fact that $I\subseteq\sqrt{I}$. $"\subseteq":$ Let $P\in R$ be a prime ideal with $I\subseteq P$. Then $\sqrt{I}\subseteq P$, i.e. $f\in\sqrt{I} \Rightarrow f\in P$: $\exists n>0:f^n\in I \Rightarrow f^n \in P \Rightarrow f^n = f\cdot f^{n-1}\in P$. If $n=1$, we are done. Otherwise, either $f\in P$ or $f^{n-1}\in P$ and continuing in the same way shows $f\in P$.

Putting all together we see that a maximal chain of prime ideals in $R/I$ corresponds to a chain of prime ideals that contain $I$ in $R$. It is also maximal, because the correspondence is inclusion-preserving due to step 2 (if the chain wasn't maximal in $R$, we could add a prime ideal containing $I$ to it, which would mean there is a corresponding prime that fits in the chain in $R/I$). The same argument holds vice versa. Step 3 then implies that the maximal chains of prime ideals containing $I$ and $\sqrt{I}$ are the same, which means that the corresponding maximal chains in $R/I$  and $R/\sqrt{I}$ have the same length, so that $\dim R/I = \dim R/\sqrt{I}$.

"Due to Hilbert's Nullstellensatz we have $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{V}(I))=\sqrt{I}$." That's not correct. Hilbert's Nullstellensatz only holds over an algebraically closed field, but $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed. Indeed, taking $I = \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$, we have $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{V}(I)) = \mathbb{R}[x] \supsetneq I$.

I think your idea is correct: $I$ and $\sqrt{I}$ are contained in exactly the same prime ideals, so the Krull dimensions of the corresponding quotient rings should be equal.

Thanks for your reply. That helped.
Regarding your first comment: In the book by Kunz you specifically find Hilbert's Nullstellensatz formulated for fields $K$ and $L$, where $K\subseteq L$ and $L$ is algebraically closed. Then, for any $I\subseteq K[x]: \mathcal{I}(\mathcal{V}L(I))=\sqrt{I}$ (taken in $K[x]$). Thus, it's only important that the field over which the affine space is defined is closed.
So in your example, $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{V}{\mathbb{C}}(x^2+1)) = {p\in\mathbb{R}[x] \vert p(\pm \text{i}) = 0} = \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$, which is radical.
